# Simple rails app performance on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, newrelic

I have a very simple rails 3.2.6 app. I've used Heroku for years to host prototypes, always on the free tier. I finally added a paid dyno on my latest app, and added New Relic to monitor performance.

I'm seeing 4500+ms request times on extremely simple pages with near-zero traffic (we haven't launched yet). New Relic says 99% of this time is spent rendering the template. This is a 75-line *completely static* haml template inside a 100-line layout. The application template has standard `- if current_user.nil?` branches.

I haven't added page caching yet. I'll do this of course, but I'd like to determine the root cause of this very poor performance before I cover it up. Any tips? What sort of response times should I expect from Heroku? On my local box in development env, the same page response time is 26ms (with assets coming in before 1.5s). New Relic reports my dynamic pages on Heroku  getting average response times of 2000ms to 6000ms.

---

*Edit*: I have page caching turned on for static / and am now seeing averages of 173ms. But I'm still concerned with my abysmal averages on dynamic pages.

Comment: Is the 4500+ms consistent or just the first hit? Heroku puts apps to sleep if they haven't been used in a while (I think after an hour of inactivity)

Comment: I thought dynos only idle for free accounts. Or are you referring to the app server releasing memory when unused? On that particular page, average is actually (surprisingly) 173ms. But I'm still curious about the other dynamic pages which have 2k to 6.5k averages. 7 requests have average of 6500ms. 8 have 4000ms. 6 have 2000ms. And the worst recorded response time is 51,000ms.

Comment: Ya I would think if you pay then it would not sleep. Could you post the worst performing page?

Comment: All non-static / worst-performing pages are behind a login and we aren't taking signups yet. Sorry :(

Comment: It might be the db on heroku. You can run a console on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console. Then do something like Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { |i| u = User.find_by_id(i); u.user_name if u } } on your dev box and on heroku and compare.

Comment: Heroku will unload your app if it goes idle for a while, so the first hit will be slow, and skew your averages. What do your Transaction Traces say in New Relic?

Comment: If you set up availability monitoring in New Relic to hit a non-static page, your dynos will stay alive since NR will hit you every 30s =)

Comment: @rkb traces say > 90% is spent in template rendering with 2,680 ms (48.2%) cpu burn. I'll try setting up availability monitoring. Thanks.

Comment: @KreeK dev: =>  25.210000   0.820000  26.030000  33.697513. heroku: =>  33.600000   2.110000  35.710000 (180.961723).

Comment: This is quite unusual. Please post the output of `heroku logs -t` during one of these requests?

Comment: @RyanDaigle here's the output of a 8324ms request: https://gist.github.com/2979089 . It looks like it's compiling my assets on the fly, even though assets:precompile ran during deploy. The next time I requested the same page, it only took 158ms.

Comment: Yep, that'll certainly do it. Can you post the output of your deploy (so we can see the asset compilation logs)?

Comment: @RyanDaigle here's the deploy: https://gist.github.com/2988760

Comment: Benchmark.measure do
  10000.times do |i|
    Rails.cache.write "foo", {foo: 1}
    Rails.cache.read "foo"
  end
end

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I have seen this on actions that consist of a few redis reads, and returning json with one value in it... 2 years later after your issue... But in my case new relic reports the time distributed through out the request, but not any of it waiting for outside requests, but it still says low CPU burn time... Heroku told me it was because of app boot ups after regular daily dyno restarts for what it is worth...

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have also said, my guess is because on the first hit in a while Heroku will have to spin up the app (in the case of free apps) to serve the request, which can make your average requests times quite slow.

Comment: This is a paid app with 2 dynos.